# UK Spouse Visa (FLR M) question - When did you last travel to the country where you were born?

Tags: united-kingdom, paperwork

I'm going through the first FLR M spouse visa application (currently on a fiancé visa inside the UK) and got stuck on a question.
Although it is obviously simple, I'd prefer to double check I'm not overthinking.

The question is: "When did you last travel to the country where you were born and/or any other country whose nationality you hold?"

Does this literally mean for example, a date such as going on a foreign holiday from said birth country and then travelling back to the birth country? As there would be no other reason.

Thanks!

[image: application question]

[image: application question]

Comment: Are you applying for this visa in your country of birth?

Comment: @phoog sorry, this is a first flr m spouse visa application, being made after now having spent time inside the uk after getting the fiance visa which allows marriage.
so inside the uk, not my birth country.

Comment: Were you living in your birth country before you came to the UK? Can you post a screenshot of this particular question and any others relevant to it?

Comment: @Traveller I was living in China where I applied for the Fiance Visa, then I came to the UK to marry and further apply for FLR M. I did try saying 'no' to question but I still get a similar question of when I last travelled to my birth country, so in this respect I'm assuming holiday travel counts... *added images to original post

Comment: For clarification. China is my birth country.

Comment: You appear to have answered no to the previous question: "Have you previously lived in a country outside the UK including your country of birth." So you have lived in China where you were born, and where were you living when you got your fiance visa?

Comment: @mkennedy I was only living in China when I applied/received the fiance visa.
Years before that I have travelled outside my birth country to other countries for regular holidays.

Comment: I don’t know if this is semantics or if it matters, but IMHO Visitor visa status (fiancé or any other visitor category) isn’t compatible with stating that you have *lived* in the UK for 4 months. Your official immigration status is *visitor*, you’re not resident in the UK and currently you have to leave by 18 Jan 2024.

Comment: I was hesitant about that, I’ll change it to 0. Still not sure about the original question though.

Comment: You have certainly answered the previous question wrong: **Yes** you have lived in a country outside the UK.

Comment: @MJeffryes Yes, sorry I think the wording confused me.
So now choosing 'yes', when it now asks me "When did you last travel to the country where you were born and/or any other country whose nationality you hold?". Then literally travelling back to said country, from a foreign holiday counts, do you know?

Comment: @traveller regarding the length of living in the UK.
in previous questions it does ask me for my current UK postal address, then to confirm that address is where i 'live' and asks what date did i start living there. So this does add to my confusion on the question regarding length of 'living' in the UK...

Comment: @PeanutMooncake IMHO it would be worth getting advice/help with your application from a [qualified UK Immigration adviser](https://www.gov.uk/find-an-immigration-adviser). The consequences of getting it wrong would be difficult to put right.

Comment: I'm with @Traveller on this.  First of all the question is confusing.  How is someone who never left the country of birth before traveling to the UK supposed to answer?  Maybe that is the answer you should give.  But maybe it isn't.  Second, you were confused and gave the wrong answer to "have you ever lived outside the UK including your country of birth?" -- can you be certain that you _won't_ be similarly confused by some other question? If you can't afford formal representation, consider a service such as https://freemovement.org.uk/immigration-application-checking-service/ (no affiliation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These open ended questions are intended to be easy to answer for those with straight situations, and more complex to answer for those with unusual situations that require more information, so the answer is to provide more information.

It's asking you when you last travelled to China because they want to know whether you are maintaining a dual residence in China and the UK without properly establishing yourself in the UK.

So the answer should be that:

- whether you have visited China since starting to live in the UK
- When you last travelled to China from anywhere (even if it was a holiday)

For example:
Since I started living in the UK, I have visited my birth country once for a few days from 01/01/05 to 05/01/05. I was living in my birth country for twenty years before moving to the UK, and my last trip was when I went on a vacation for one week to India between 05/05/01 and 12/05/01.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically two questions in one, or one question with two parts.

> When did you last travel to the country where you were born

Can't be simpler than that... If you were born in China, then it means: *"When did you last travel **to** China?* TO, not from. You should be able to remember the last time you went to China.

> and/or any other country whose nationality you hold?

And if you hold currently another citizenship, besides/instead of PRC, when was the last time you visited this country / these countries? Again, TO, not from.

They basically want to know when you last visited home.